# MYSQL Combine date and time field to datatime value

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have two columns in my table that I want o combine, to later check the value.

The first column is `open_date`    (DATATYPE = DATE)

The second column is `open_time`   (DATATYPE = TIME)

I want to combine the values, like this: 2013-04-26 12:34:57

And then i have to check if the combined datetime is earlier than today.

This is my Query:

```
SELECT * FROM blog_articles WHERE concat(open_date,' ',open_time) <= DATETIME()
```

But I get the followin error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '() ORDER BY `open_date` DESC 
LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [`now()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) not `datetime()` (which is a datatype, not a function).

Secondly, it is better to build your datetime with the [timestamp()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestamp) function:

```
SELECT * FROM blog_articles
WHERE timestamp(open_date,open_time) <= NOW()
```